# Resize height with width

Tags: html, css

I want that the div start with 350px for height and then u can resize it close to 0px due to width.

`<div id="banner">` `</div>`

in css

`#banner{width: 100%; height: calc(width * 0.23874488403);}`

Comment: default value isn't 0 but none

Comment: @TemaniAfif thx, but can i chane it ?

Comment: you already did but your question is acutally unclear. it's like you need min-height and not max-height

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by giving the `#banner` a `width: 99vw`, and then using calc to create a height proportional to it. I used a variable here so that it can be set in `:root` and not repeated inside `#banner`. Then set the `max-height: 350px`:

```css
html,body{margin:0}

:root{
    --width: 99vw;
}

#banner{
    width: var(--width); 
    max-height: 350px;
    height: calc(var(--width) * 0.24);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:solid 2px dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner"> </div>
```